# import airflow -> ImportError: cannot import name version (with Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, python-2.x, airflow

Trying the following code:

```
import airflow
```

I received the following error on python 2.7 in Jupyter Notebook:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-6452413eb644> in <module>()
----> 1 import airflow
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\airflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     26 """
     27 from builtins import object
---> 28 from airflow import version
     29 from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
     30 
ImportError: cannot import name version
```

I have seen similar issues on the forum, but there were no definitive answers to this issue.

Comment: thx for the formatting karel

Comment: Please give us your Airflow version.

Comment: apache-airflow v1.10.2

Comment: I am curious about reason you want to import airflow in Notebook.

Comment: that is my preferred dev environment, my general line of work is data analysis. would you recommend trying a diff dev environment to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade your flask version

pip install --force-reinstall Flask==1.0.2

Comment: "...apache-airflow has requirement flask<0.31, >=0.12.4, but you'll have flask 1.0.2 which is incompatible..."